# Removing of index.php in CodeIgniter not working in Laragon

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, nginx, laragon

I want to remove the `index.php` from URL in CodeIgniter while using `Laragon`

I have edited the `.htaccess` file in CodeIgniter and applied a rule; I also changed the `index_page` variable to empty string in `application/config/config.php`.

It, as expected, works completely fine in a web environment setup using `WampServer/xampserver` but fails when using `Laragon`.

The problem may be with the Laragon environment but I don’t know how to fix it.

How can I make it work in a `Laragon environment`? (As Working in Wampserver).

My `.htaccess` file contains the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myFolder/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: can you put your `.htaccess` file here

Comment: check mod_rewrite enable in laragon

Comment: Doesn't Laragon use Nginx? In that case, your htaccess-file won't be used at all since it's an Apache file.

Comment: try this https://programmingtechnologyworld.blogspot.com/2018/04/remove-indexphp-from-url-using-by.html

Comment: mod_rewrite is enable in laragon, i have checked it, .htaccess is also fine as it is working properly in wamp server

Comment: Yes exactly it use Nginx, but how to configure in order to remove index.php from URL. @MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem then by getting some help on Laragon community

The fix is actually simple.

Laragon is compiled with its `httpd.conf` set to reject overwrite on the document root.

To edit this, check the file on

```
{LARAGON_ROOT}/bin/apache/httpd{other-version-details}/conf/httpd.conf
```

and the file somewhere around line 251 to 278 change `AllowOverride` to `All` and restart your Laragon Server.

That fixes it

**NOTE:**

You have to do settings in your codeIgniter, like your `index_page` variable should be empty in

```
application/config/config.php
```

> $config['index_page'] = "";

And the `.htaccess` file contains the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /yourFolderName/index.php/$1 [L]
```

If still it doesn't work, find all `AllowOverride None` in `httpd.conf` and change them to `AllowOverride All`. Restart your computer if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In `C:\laragon\etc\apache2\sites-enabled` you are going to find all the v-hosts of laragon you have in your working directory.

When you find the codeigniter one and you open to edit it you are going to see a normal apache `VirtualHost`.

Change this line:     `<Directory "C:/workspace/my_project">`

to : `<Directory "C:/workspace/my_project/index.html">`

Rename the laragon .conf file and remove `auto.` from the file name.

Restart everything.

*careful to open the right v-host. Laragon creates 2 v-hosts, 1 with your extension defined in settings and one with .com extension.*

Edit:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "C:/laragon/www/gmap_polygons/application/""
    ServerName gmap_polygons.dev 
    ServerAlias *.gmap_polygons.dev 
    <Directory "C:/workspace/woo-backend-laravel/application/">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# If you want to use SSL, enable it by going to Menu > Apache > SSL > Enabled
```

Comment: I found .conf file of my project in that folder sites-enabled, I opened it, rename directory name as you mention, restart everything, but it didn't work

Comment: Can you modify the DocumentRoot like above to include the index.html, as well and restart? Also are you sure it's the index.html and not the index.php you want to bypass?

Comment: let me check it

Comment: I also modify the DocumentRoot. When i run it without including index.php it still shows me 404 not found, and it remove index.html from .conf file automatically

Comment: My bad, after you do the changes please remove the `auto` from the conf file name

Comment: I renamed this auto.gmap_polygons.dev.conf to this gmap_polygons.dev.conf, doesn't work,

Comment: change the .dev extension to .test. New browsers have stopped support .dev and creates problems (chrome for example)

Comment: this is the code inside .conf file
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "C:/laragon/www/gmap_polygons/index.html"
    ServerName gmap_polygons.dev
    ServerAlias *.gmap_polygons.dev
    <Directory "C:/laragon/www/gmap_polygons/index.html">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# If you want to use SSL, enable it by going to Menu > Apache > SSL > Enabled

Comment: it still doesn't works, i renamed to this gmap_polygons.test.conf, I have checked it in Microsoft Edge. also doesn't work there

Comment: Edited my answer can you try now? Don't forget to restart

Comment: I applied the edited, it now give me error, service apache cannot start: Reasons, then there are a lot of reasons

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193314/discussion-between-tufail-ahmad-and-pr1nc3).